# Python subprocess Exec format error

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, subprocess

Sorry if this question is dumb. I am using python `subprocess` statement to call a .bat file in Ubuntu (Natty 11.04), however, I got error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pfam_picloud.py", line 40, in <module>
    a=subprocess.Popen(src2, shell=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1213, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

#### run this python file

```
$python pfam_picloud.py
```

#### Python code (pfam_picloud.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
met="wTest.dvf"
run="run_pfam.bat"
inp="pfam_input.PFA"
import os
import stat
import shutil
import subprocess
import string
import random
# Generate a random ID for file save
def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
name_temp=id_generator()
cwd=os.getcwd()
src=cwd
src1=cwd+'/'+name_temp
if not os.path.exists(src1):
    os.makedirs(src1)
else:
    shutil.rmtree(src1)
    os.makedirs(src1)
##
shutil.copy(src+"/"+run,src1)
shutil.copy(src+"/"+met,src1)
shutil.copy(cwd+"/pfam_pi.exe",src1)
shutil.copy(src+"/"+inp,src1)
#
src2=src1+"/run_pfam.bat"
os.chdir(src1)
a=subprocess.Popen(src2, shell=0)
a.wait()
```

#### bash file (run_pfam.bat)

```
#!/bin/sh
./pfam_pi.exe pfam_input.PFA
```

I can successfully run this bash file in Ubuntu. So I guess, I messed up something in my Python script. Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks for any inputs.

#### EDIT

the file `pfam_pi.exe` is a Linux executable. I compiled it in Ubuntu. Sorry for the confusion.

#### update

Well, I got different types of error now. 
1. With `#!/bin/sh`, it said `No such file or directory`. 
2. With `/bin/sh`, it said `exec format error`. 
3. If I sent everything as arguments `a=subprocess.Popen(['./pfam_pi.exe', 'inp', 'src1'], shell=0)`, it said `end of line symbol error`

Comment: Something tells me you're trying to execute a Windows program on Linux. What does `file pfam_pi.exe` say?

Comment: the pfam_pi.exe was compiled in Ubuntu. I just called it .exe sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is the **script** (that's not a BAT file, please don't use Windows terms when working on Linux) marked executable?

Comment: Does inp and src1 contain end of line symbols?

Comment: @larsmans: If I understand you correctly. I give the python script, the bat file, and the Linux executable file full permissions.

Comment: @larsmans: it would be the end-of-line difference between 'Linux' and 'windows'. But I assume `bash` shell can overcome this, since it works fine in Ubuntu terminal '$./pfam_pi.exe pfam_input.PFA'

Comment: The problem should be with the parameters you actually pass to Popen. I would prefer to see a full traceback for an error #3 (end of line). The example you gave us has 'inp' and 'src1' strings an the call to Popen. Is it a typo? And if it is, and really you pass variables src and inp1, print their values.

Comment: @Ellioh: Thanks for your comments. I found once I changed the shell=1, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

@Ellioh: Thanks for your comments. I found once I changed the shell=1, problem is solved. – tao.hong

Comment: That would be useful, so that someone looking for the solution can easily identify it. Or you might post your solution as another answer, so that you can get reputation points for it; I could then (vote to) delete my copied answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `wine` (you should have it installed) and pass `pfam_pi.exe` to it as a parameter. Maybe `pfam_pi.exe` is not a Linux executable. :-) Certainly, executable file extensions are not meaningful on Linux, but probably it really is a Windows program, otherwise I hardly can imagine it named `pfam_pi.exe`.

However, if it is a Linux executable, note `subprocess.Popen` accepts a list of args (the first element is the program itself), not a command line:

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I compiled the pfam_pi.exe on Ubuntu. So it is a Linux executable.

Comment: Yes, I see. Probably you are trying to create a configuration that can be run with the same `.bat` file both on Linux and Windows...

Comment: Based on your sample code, does that mean `subprocess` could not run `.bat` file? I have tested my approach in Window, which works fine...

Comment: If it has executable flag and #!/bin/sh in the beginning, it should work. But you may also try running /bin/sh explicitly, at least to locate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried your approach but got different error messages. Please see my updates for detail.