# Python subprocess Popen passing arguments

Tags: python, shell

Im trying to call a shell script from my python with a parameter but the parameter is not being passed

My Shellscript:

```
echo "Inside shell"
echo $0
echo $1
cd $1
pwd
for file in *.csv
do
  split -l 50000 -d -a 4  "$file" "$file"
done
echo "Outside shell"
```

with shell=True

```
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cmd = [os.path.join(this_dir,'split.sh'),fileslocation]
print 'cmd = ', cmd
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
```

The parameters are not being passed correctly...

with Shell=True removed

```
cmd =  ['/opt/sw/p3/src/PricesPaidAPI/split.sh', '../cookedData']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_rename.py", line 23, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python raise child\_exception OSError: \[Errno 8\] Exec format error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925909/python-raise-child-exception-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error)  (Your shell script is missing the shebang...)

Comment: @Wooble I wouldn't say the link you provided answers this question. It clearly says the OP had to recompile his program, and it wasn't a script. Shebang was just a suggestion that wasn't confirmed. Although it might be right.

Comment: The accepted answer gives the 2 possibilities that would cause the OP's error, and from the script he pasted in the question, you can see that there's no shebang line.

Comment: @Wooble Again. It is an unconfrimed suggestion, isn't it? Are you sure it worked? Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072508/python-subprocess-exec-format-error some one had a shebang and it seems like it didn't work. Had to use `shell=True`.

Comment: I'm sure it will work for the OP of this question, yes. `shell=True` is a bad idea, and the OP of that other question could have fixed it another way.

Comment: @Wooble I know, I've just checked it. But even if the question you linked suggested a good answer it wasn't confirmed there. The other one was. That is a fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I dunno if this should be a dupe, or not (as per comments). But it is a fact that shebang helps. And here is the confirmation.

popen_test.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["./dummy.sh", "test"])
```

noshebang.sh:

```
echo "Echoing: $1"
```

This results with `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`. It is because OS expects the file to be executable (duh). However, a `#!` - shebang in a 1st line is a special mark for the system, that the file should be executed in the shell environment specified by it. So it can be treated as an executable, even though it is not. So:

shebang.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Echoing: $1"
```

Works.

It is essentially the same as python's `shell=True`. Just the system takes care of it. IMO it is a bit harder to inject random code with this approach. So I would suggest going for it.